Is the Beta index of the zero divisor graph of a finite commutative unital ring uniformly far from 1?
Is  there a  uniform upper  bound $M<1$  for  the  Beta  index of  the  zero  divisor  graph of  an arbitrary  finite  unital  commutative  ring?
In the  other word  is  there a  positive  number $0<M<1$ with the following  property:
For  every  finite  commutative  unital  ring $R$,  which is  not a  field, the  following number is  less than $M$:
$$\frac{\# \{(a,b)\mid ab=0, a\neq 0, b\neq 0\}}{\# \{\text{all (a,b) where  a,b are non trivial zero divisors of  R}\}}$$
So  the  question asks:  can this fraction  be arbitrary  close to  1? is  there  a  name  or  terminology  for  this  quantity  associated  to a finite  commutative  unital ring?

Vote to  close?  without any explanation?

A possible  relation to number theory?  for a  compound number $n$ let $\eta(n)$ be the  mentioned  quantity  for  the  ring $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}$

Consider the ring $R := \mathbb{Z}/(4)$ and let $[n] := n + (4)$. Then $R$ contains exactly one zero divisor, namely $[2]$ unless we also count $0$ as a zero divisor. Regardless of which convention we follow the quotient you are interested in is $\geq 1$ for this particular choice of $R$, since the set of pairs of zero divisors in $R$ is a subset of $$\{(0, 0),\, (0, [2]),\, ([2], 0),\, ([2], [2])\}, $$ and for all elements $(a, b)$ in this set we have $ab=0$.
In short, the answer to your question is that no, there does not exist any such bound $M$.

I  do not  consider  $0$  as  zero  divisor  and  I  do no  consider the  obvious  case  which leads  to  obvios  answer  for  example n=4.   I  am interested in non obvious  case for example  for  n=6 $\eta(6)=4/9$  Do you have any idea on asymptotic  behaviour of  $\eta$ as  n goes infinity?

You could argue similarly for $n=p^2$ with $p$ any prime. Thus there exist arbitrarily large $n$ for which $\eta (n) \geq 1$.

How that is  possible? Please look at the  quotient in the post the numerator is less than denominator

As defined, the numerator counts the number of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ such that $ab=0$ without further restrictions. Thus it contains for instance pairs such as $(a,0)$ and $(0,a)$ for every $a \in R$, This inevitably leads to $\eta(p^2) > 1$ for every prime $p$. However, I suspect that  you meant pairs $(a,b)$ for which $ab=0$ and $a,b \neq 0$. In this case the same reasoning as for $p=2$ gives that $\eta(p^2)=1$ for all primes $p$, which is why I did not argue for a strict inequality in my answer.

Essentially you are saying that if $R$ has exactly one zero divisor, then we get that the fraction is $\geq 1$ (depending on the formulation), right? Do you have any intuition on what happens if there are more than one zero divisor? Also, very nice answer (+1).

@Ost  No it  does not  contain (0,a). Because  I exclude trivial case. I edit the  question. But trhe idea  is  simple:  we  wish  to  know  the  extent the  vertices of  zero  divisors  are  connected to each other

@Ost  Yes  you  are  right. The  question need  improvement. For example  characterization of  rings  for  whiuch the fraction is 1,  or  some thing like  that (+1)

@SeverinSchraven                For  relatively primes  m, n  what  can be said  about $\eta(mn)?$

I am  curious   about the  range of  $\eta$  when $R$ varies  among all possible  finite  unital rings

@SeverinSchraven  How  can one  extend  this  definition to some  particular  rings, for  example inductive limit  of  finite  rings  or  the  group  rings $\mathbb{C}G$. For  the  later instead of  counting $#$ one may  think  to  a  possible  measure  naturally arise  from the  Haar measure of G

@SeverinSchraven  Regarding my last phrase I  am  inspired by haar measure  analogy of the  following  fact in group theory: if  more than 3/4 of  ellements of  G  commute then the  group is abelian. But I think  there is  a  measure analogues of this  fact for  topological groups

Any way  what is  a  natural  measure on $\mathbb{C}G$ appropriate  for  investigation of  zero  divisors?

@SeverinSchraven Yes, that is right. However, we can achieve equality with more than one zero divisor. Let for instance $k$ be any finite field and $R:=k[\varepsilon] \simeq k[x]/(x^2)$ the algebra of dual numbers over $k$. The zero divisors of $R$ are then precisely $a\varepsilon$ for $a$ some nonzero element of $k$ and the product of any such pair is $0$. Thus the quotient in the post is again exactly equal to $1$ for this choice of $R$ and since we can choose $k$ to be arbitrarily large we can create examples of the quotient being equal to $1$ with arbitrarily many zero divisiors in $R$.

@AliTaghavi When $m,, n$ are relatively prime we get that $\mathbb{Z}/(nm)\simeq\mathbb{Z}/(n)\times\mathbb{Z}/(m)=:R$. There are two ways of forming pairs of zero divisors whose product is $0$ in $R$: either take something of the form $\big( (a,0),, (0,b)\big)$ where $a, b\neq 0$ or a pair of the form $\big((a,b),, (a',b')\big)$ where $(a,a')$ and $(b,b')$ are pairs that are counted by $z(n)$ and $z(m)$ respectively. This can be used to show that $z(nm)=2(n-1)(m-1)+z(n)z(m)$. The denominator equals $(nm-\varphi(n)\varphi(m)-1)^2$, where $\varphi$ denotes the Euler $\varphi$ function.

@Ost That's an awesome example! Unfortunately, I cannot upvote twice

@SeverinSchraven  The  twice upvote is impossible  but you can give this  answer  at least  50  reputation. There  is  a  bounty  option devoted to  present reputation to  an  outstanding   existing   answer. If  you  find  an  answer  which  meet  outstanding  property which  cover all  possible explicit and  implicit  goals  of  the  question  you  can  devote  such a  bounty.  Implicit  goals consist  of (not  limited to) some  other  commented questions added to this  post.

@SeverinSchraven  However  myself  I  upvoted the  answer but I think that the  idea behnd the question can be improved  and  expanded
